# Amalgamated Product, $G_1*_HG_2$ is surjective $\iff$ $G = \langle G_1\coprod G_2\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, universal-property, free-product

Suppose we are given groups $G_1,G_2$ and some subgroup $H$ of $G_1$ and $G_2$ and let $G_1*_HG_2$ denote the amalgamated free product.

I stumbled upon the following claim:

> $G$  is generated by $G_1\sqcup G_2$ $\iff$ $G_1*_HG_2 \to G$ is
> surjective.

Now i've tried to think about this in terms of the universal property together with the definition of the amalgamated free product as the quotient of a free group $F\langle G_1,G_2\rangle$ modulo the usual relations. But i still struggle to see why this is true.

Does this follow from descending to the quotient? Could someone elaborate?

Side-Question: Is $F\langle G_1,G_2\rangle$ the same as $F\langle G_1\sqcup G_2\rangle$?

("$\sqcup$" denotes the disjoint union)

Comment: You mean the union of the underlying sets of the subgroups. It doesn't make sense to talk about the "disjoint union of groups". In any case, the claim follows directly from the fact that the amalgamated sum is generated by the union. If you want to use universal properties only, you will have to use the epimorphism characterization of generating sets and the fact that epis of groups are surjective (non-trivial).

Comment: And $G$ is probably supposed to be a group containing $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your comments and observations. They help a lot. The epimorphism characterization is what i was looking for.